# How to change the iframe src?

Tags: javascript, iframe

So on my page I am using Iframe to display another webpage inside it. I want to set up an Array with many webpage (as much as I want) and I want to make 2 buttons so every time I click the Next button it will change the page inside the iframe tag that I have. My question is how can I setup the 2 buttons (Next and previous) so when I click them I will change accordingly to Array set up ?

```
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>Untitled Document</title> 
  </head> 

  var webpageArray = new Array()
  webpageArray[0]= "web0.com/"; 
  webpageArray[1]= "web1.com/"; 
  webpageArray[2]= "web2.com/"; 

  <iframe id="myframe" src="web1.com"></iframe> 

  loadNextPage = function() { 
    var iframe = document.getElementById("myframe"); 
    var src = webpageArray[1]; 
    iframe.src = src; 
    return; 
  } 
  <body>  
    <a href="" onclick="LoadNextPage"> Next Web Page >> </a> 
  </body> 
  </html>
```

Comment: So you haven't done anything yet?

Comment: If you show us your code, we can help fix it - please don't make us write everything from scratch, it takes much more effort on our part and you will learn nothing that way. Spend a little time on this yourself, you should *enjoy* writing javascript, not avoid it! Come back when you have a serious or specific question or [edit] this one into something less vague.

Comment: Your html/script is invalid. You need to wrap the script in script tags and have the iframe and link inside the body tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works - using PLAIN javascript and yes, an inline handler - it should be attached in onload, but let's take it one thing at a time

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/D2pNN/)

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>Untitled Document</title> 
    <script>
      var cnt=0,webpageArray = [
        "http://cnn.com/",
        "http://msn.com/", 
        "http://yahoo.com/"
      ]; 

      function loadNextPage(dir) {   
        cnt+=dir;
        if (cnt<0) cnt=webpageArray.length-1; // wrap
        else if (cnt>= webpageArray.length) cnt=0; // wrap
        var iframe = document.getElementById("myframe"); 
        iframe.src = webpageArray[cnt]; 
        return false; // mandatory!
      } 
    </script>
  </head> 

  <body>  
  <iframe id="myframe" src="http://cnn.com/"></iframe> 

  <a href="#" onclick="return loadNextPage(-1)"> << Previus Web Page </a> | 
  <a href="#" onclick="return loadNextPage(1)"> Next Web Page >> </a> 
  </body> 
  </html>
```

---

jQuery version

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4NkER/)

```
var cnt=0,webpageArray = [
  "http://cnn.com/",
  "http://msn.com/", 
  "http://yahoo.com/"
]; 

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#prev, #next").click(function(e) {
    cnt+=this.id=="next"?1:-1;
    if (cnt<0) cnt=webpageArray.length-1; // wrap
    else if (cnt>= webpageArray.length) cnt=0; // wrap
    $("#myframe").attr("src", webpageArray[cnt]);
    return false;
  });
});    

<iframe id="myframe" src="http://cnn.com"></iframe> <br />
<a href="#" id="prev"> << Previous Web Page </a> | 
<a href="#" id="next"> Next Web Page >> </a>
```

Comment: Updated plain version to have a previous link too

Answer (score 0):

Junk way

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
flag = 0;
SrcList = new Array("http://www.google.com", "http://www.27nov.fr", "http://www.perdu.com");
function NextSrc(){
    if(flag < SrcList.length - 1){
    flag++;
    ChangeSrc(SrcList[flag]);
    }
    return false;
}
function PrevSrc(){
    if(flag > 0){
    flag--;
    ChangeSrc(SrcList[flag]);
    }
    return false;

}
function ChangeSrc(src){
    var iframe = document.getElementById('Myiframe');
    iframe.setAttribute('src',src);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="#" onclick="PrevSrc()">Prev</a> - <a href="#" onclick="NextSrc()">Next</a></p>
<iframe id="Myiframe" src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="640" height="480">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please return false on the onclick handlers!
Why change the source onload? Why call the index for flag? It is not a flag. There is no var called MaxLenght and if there were, spell it maxLength or just use the length of the array
Also please read http://w3fools.com/

Comment: How can I make it rotrate back when I reach the last page ? (please edit your own code)

Answer (score -2):

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="some web page"></iframe>

loadNextPage = function() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
    var src = webpageArray[2];
    iframe.src = src;
    return;
}
```

But I donot recommend this process.

Comment: Where is the counter and the change of the IDX and the coding of directions?

Comment: The counter is not my look out. The person who asked this question have already implemented the code. OK ?

Comment: I tried to make this work for the last couples days, but it just did not work for me :( I watched many tutorials and I really want to learn more. Any way this is what I have so far with your help, but it is not working at all (I know i am missing alot)

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
var webpageArray = new Array()
webpageArray[0]= "http://web0.com/"
webpageArray[1]= "http://web1.com/"
webpageArray[2]= "http://web2.com/"


<iframe id="myframe" src="web1.com"></iframe>

loadNextPage = function() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
    var src = webpageArray[1];
    iframe.src = src;
    return;
}


<body>

<a href="" onclick="LoadNextPage"> Next Web Page >> </a>

</body>
</html>

Comment: I added that to the question - but it does not make any sense. You need script tags and such