# Dynamically updating content within HTML section or div

Tags: javascript, css, html, rss

I have 3 table cells that I am using to display information. They span 100% width of a webpage. I need to be able to somehow have the ability to update the content within the cells with new information as and when, and with the potential of having scroll bars for each cell.

I am thinking RSS or is there a better way?

Comment: Show us a http://jsfiddle.net/ or something like this please :)

Comment: Do you want to update the table cells when an external file is updated? Or do you just want to dynamically change the content of a table cell?

Comment: RSS is not even related to your question unless you want the content to update based on an RSS Feed. As far as CSS, you can set `td { overflow-y: auto; }` after setting it's height. You'll need to use Javascript to update your cells dynamically. There's plenty of tutorials out there to help you understand how to use AJAX calls to dynamically update content in a page.

Answer (score 0):

You could place an iFrame into each cell. This would allow you to reference other content and display scroll bars if needed.

For example:

```
<table width="100%>
    <tr>
         <td width="33%"><iframe src="http://YourSourceContentUrlHere" scrolling="yes"></iframe></td>
         <td width="34%"><iframe src="http://YourSourceContentUrlHere" scrolling="yes"></iframe></td>
         <td width="33%"><iframe src="http://YourSourceContentUrlHere" scrolling="yes"></iframe></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You'll need to set heights and maybe adjust the cell widths.
If you need to change the URL of iframes after the page has loaded then have a look at this post:
[How to change the iframe src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785779/how-to-change-the-iframe-src)